# GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) network traffic monitoring of PODs for detailed byte based billing

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have the following situation:

I have a bunch of deployed things in multiple GKE clusters. I would like to generate billing for my customers who use those deployments. However, I don't want to bill them for network traffic they aren't generating, but my cluster is generating, so inter region / AZ communication is probably my doing, I don't want to bill them for that.

However, I do would like to bill them for traffic they used on / bytes basis. For this, I require to monitor outgoing and incoming traffic, by bytes, and detect if they are in the same region / AZ that the POD in question is currently in.

I heard a podcast recently that there is supposed to be an API for that. Is anyone aware of such a thing that would help me monitor network traffic in such granularity?

Note: The setup is a bit weird so I don't have individual VPCs for deployed apps, which means I can't really use VPC flow logs. It's also not enough to monitor VMs since multiple pods could be on the same VM anyways.

Does anyone know anything at all that could move me along into the right direction?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [GKE usage metering](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/gke-usage-metering-whose-line-item-is-it-anyway) might be of interest to you. Step by step can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-usage-metering). GKE metering will fetch resource usage/consumption from metrics servers, converts the consumption data to usage records and sends the records to a different BigQuery table in the same dataset.

Comment: Cool! That sounds exactly what I'm looking for. I'll take a quick peek, before I accept your answer. :)) Thank you!

Comment: so I did some reading. Do I see correctly that this only enables some custom metrics with collectd and kubernetes metrics? I mean I can add a custom metric of some sort, but as far as I can see, this only collects in-out bytes and that's it. I need more information than that. :( Like, IP of src and dst at the very least. I also need to detect if said IP is in the same region or not.